# Golang Getopt V2: Parse multiple duplicate flags

Tags: go, getopt

I am new to golang and I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem using getopt version 2.

```
./example -v i=5 -v j=6 -v k=7
```

I want to use the flag v as indicated here https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html

Comment: I had the same issue recently and I built a little helper package for it [here](https://github.com/chaseisabelle/flagz). It's not using getopt, though. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it was really useful.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is able to parse multiple options of the same flag, so for the above example it will print [i=5 j=6 k=7]

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/pborman/getopt/v2"
  "fmt"
  "runtime"
  "github.com/gthd/helper"
)

var (
  value helper.Helper
)

func init() {
 getopt.FlagLong(&value, "string", 'v', "strings")
}

func main() {
  getopt.Parse()
  strings := value.ParseMultipleOptions()
  fmt.Println(strings)
}
```

While helper file is

```
package helper

import (
    "strings"
    "github.com/pborman/getopt/v2"
)

type Helper []string

func (h *Helper) Set(str string, opt getopt.Option) error {
    *h = append(*h, str)
    _ = opt
    return nil
}

func (h *Helper) String() string {
    return strings.Join(h.Array(), ", ")
}

func (h *Helper) Array() []string {
    return *h
}

func (h *Helper) ParseMultipleOptions() []string {
    return h.Array()
}
```